# How to assign series of numbers to a single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a from input that contains series of numbers separate by white space that looks like this:

```
$input = "1243 984 4692 9465 ";
```

Is there any way to convert this to an array that keeps those numbers like this looks like this:

```
$array_numbers[0] = 1243 
$array_numbers[1] = 984 
$array_numbers[2] = 4692
$array_numbers[3] = 9465
```

Any help on this will be much appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Seriously! You've never come across PHP's [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function before?

Comment: @MarkBaker maybe because the OP is always using `split` ?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit If OP Is always using split(), then they still know how to do what they're asking

Comment: Seriously @MarkBaker,  you've never come across a neophyte coder before ?

Comment: I've never come across anybody that neophyte.... usually neophyte coders use explode for __everything__, even when they shouldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim and explode will do that for you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Trim removes the whitespace at the end, which if it stays will cause an empty entry in the array.

```
$input = "1243 984 4692 9465 ";
$array_numbers = explode(' ', trim($input));
```

Comment: Job Done! thx a lot guys!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$array_numbers = explode(' ', trim($input));
```

Comment: Trim the input before, or you'll have empty elements at the beginning and end if there is as single space

Comment: Yeah You Right @RiccardoC Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function in php that separate the content of your string into an array of string, then convert each elements of array items into integer using intVal() function in php
See sample code below

```
<?php
     $hello = "12 34 45 56 78";
     $result = array();
     $result = explode(" ", $hello);
     for($j=0; $j<count($result); $j++){    
         echo intval( $result[$j] )."</br>";
    }
?>
```